# What is a good strategy to save user premium subscription for a web app with Azure AD B2C as user management system?

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor Server web app that will have locked features only accessible via paid subscription (payment handled with stripe).

I am using Azure AD B2C for user management/authentication.

I also have an Android and iOS app built with Xamarin, from which users will be able to subscribe to the service (payment handled with Android/iOS built-in payment service), and therefore have full access to the web app.

What is the right approach to save the fact that a user has completed payment, and retrieve that data on future sign up ?

I read about custom attributes in Azure AD B2C, so maybe I should build the system on top of Azure AD B2C, but I am not sure it is the appropriate approach for this use case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a custom policy and custom attributes if you have a simple system where you just want to store a value and deny access during login if the value is not set.

For anything more complicated, rather store all the details in a DB and access it via a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile).

**Update**

You can access the attribute direct from custom policies. You just read and write it like any other attribute.

If you want to use the Graph API, be aware the [name is different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#manage-extension-attributes-through-microsoft-graph).

Comment: The system is very simple: as you mentioned, I only need to store a boolean value (IsPremiumAccount), and retrieve it at login. It seems that I need to create a boolean custom attribute on Azure for users, and then use the Graph API to get and update that value. Do you confirm it is the right approach ?